# A suitable JavaScript graph library for showing results of partial differential equations

Tags: javascript, graphs, math, 3d

I am handling a project which solves [partial differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation). The solution is a 3D graph in most cases. Which JavaScript library is suitable for me to display the result?

Example graph:

[image: graph]

Comment: Those 'results of partial differential equations': in what format are they? I.e. what is your inut data for the library?